# Beast Sense and carrying items

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, barbarian, rituals

If I'm controlling a creature with Beast Sense, are they able to carry items within reason with respect to their size? The Beast Sense description doesn't say anything about interaction with the animal.

E.g. Could my bat that I'm controlling carry a key back to my character?

Comment: Beast Sense may be the best sense, but I've fixed the typos in the post :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Beast sense* does not let you control the target. You can only "borrow" its senses. You will have to find another way to control or influence the beast. (Eg. you could convince it using *speak with animals*.)